# При нажатии на кнопку выводит:UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter

````
def click():
    x=x+1
from tkinter import*
tk=Tk()
tk.title("Вы использовали кнопку раз")
btn=Button(tk, text=("x"), font="Courier 100", fg="grey", bg="snow",command=click)
btn.pack()
def click():
    x=x+1
from tkinter import*
tk=Tk()
tk.title("Вы использовали кнопку раз")
btn=Button(tk, text=("x"), font="Courier 100", fg="grey", bg="snow",command=click)
btn.pack()```
````

Answer (score 3):

```
x=0
def click():
    global x
    x=x+1
from tkinter import*

tk=Tk()
tk.title("Вы использовали кнопку раз")
btn=Button(tk, text=("x"), font="Courier 100", fg="grey", bg="snow",command=click)
btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```